# shape to image in clipper flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, clip-path

i'm getting shape like  this

[image]

my code:

```
@override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = new Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);
      var firstControlPoint = Offset(0, size.height -80);
    var firstEndPoint = Offset(size.width/2, size.height -60);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(firstControlPoint.dx, firstControlPoint.dy,
        firstEndPoint.dx, firstEndPoint.dy);
    var secondControlPoint = Offset(size.width  , size.height - 95);
    var secondEndPoint = Offset(size.width, size.height / 1.8);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(secondControlPoint.dx, secondControlPoint.dy,
        secondEndPoint.dx, secondEndPoint.dy);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height - 30);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }
```

I want to shape image like this

[image]

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using your `firstEndPoint.dy` it seems like the curve is much smoother. Here the code:

```dart
class MyClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0.0, size.height);
    final firstControlPoint = Offset(0, size.height - 80);
    final firstEndPoint = Offset(size.width / 2, size.height - 60);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(firstControlPoint.dx, firstControlPoint.dy,
        firstEndPoint.dx, firstEndPoint.dy);
    
    // Make your secondControlPoint start with firstEndPoint.dy
    final secondControlPoint = Offset(size.width, firstEndPoint.dy);
    final secondEndPoint = Offset(size.width, size.height / 1.8);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(secondControlPoint.dx, secondControlPoint.dy,
        secondEndPoint.dx, secondEndPoint.dy);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height - 30);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0.0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  // ...
}
```

[Try code on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/9bfc8f9b23b716baa332db618ea481b8)

[image]